# How to get selected text,value from the dropdown and assign into list object in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Here I'm using angularjs with Web API. I want to get selected dropdown list values and assign into list object and then it'll save into DB. Here is my code.

```js
selectModule.controller("selectStateController", function ($scope) {
$scope.ILBasicInfoDTO.PYROrNonResidencyStateInfo.TaxpayerEarnedIncomeFromOtherState = { StateID: 10, StateName: 'Illinois' }, { StateID: 11, StateName: 'New York' }, { StateID: 12, StateName: 'Michigan' }, { StateID: 13, StateName: 'Georgia' }, { StateID: 14, StateName: 'California' };

$.ajax({
      url: serviceUrl + 'il/persistilbasicinfo',
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      async: true,            
      data: JSON.stringify({
                userId: userId,
                TaxReturnData:
                   {
                       UserDataId: userDataId,
                       TaxData: JSON.stringify($scope.ILBasicInfoDTO),
                       IsTaxMeterCall: false
                   },
            }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                ErrorHandling(jqXHR, errorThrown);
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                if (data != null) {

                }

            }
        })
});
```

```html
<select id="ddlSpouseEearnedIncomeFromOtherState0" ng-model="ILBasicInfoDTO.PYROrNonResidencyStateInfo.TaxpayerEarnedIncomeFromOtherState">
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<option ng-repeat="TStatesExceptIL in TaxpayerStatesExceptILAndReciprocalStates" ng-value="TStatesExceptIL.StateId">{{TStatesExceptIL.StateCode}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You did not mentioned your problem clearly. What problem you are facing with this code?

Comment: When i get selected dropdown value from the ng-model i can't save into the db on Json format. Eg: If I currently selected to the model value it can automatically added $$hashKey({"StateId":19,"$$hashKey","0"} ) to the list obj and i used angular.toJson to remove the $$hashKey and it has been reomved from the list obj but it can given the following error. Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[JTL.Tax1040.BusinessObject.State]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. How can i solve?

Comment: First of all do not use jquery ajax on angular code. use $http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the selected text and value, pass the complete object as `ng-value`:

```
<select id="ddlSpouseEearnedIncomeFromOtherState0" ng-model="ILBasicInfoDTO.PYROrNonResidencyStateInfo.TaxpayerEarnedIncomeFromOtherState">

 <option value="">--Select--</option>
 <option ng-repeat="TStatesExceptIL in TaxpayerStatesExceptILAndReciprocalStates" ng-value="TStatesExceptIL">{{TStatesExceptIL.StateCode}}</option>
</select>
```

Now you can get the text and value from `$scope` variable which you have binded to `ng-model` i.e `$scope.ILBasicInfoDTO.PYROrNonResidencyStateInfo.TaxpayerEarnedIncomeFromOtherState`

Text as: `$scope.ILBasicInfoDTO.PYROrNonResidencyStateInfo.TaxpayerEarnedIncomeFromOtherState.StateCode`

value as: `$scope.ILBasicInfoDTO.PYROrNonResidencyStateInfo.TaxpayerEarnedIncomeFromOtherState.StateId`